# Уникальная строчка для каждой публикации

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php8

Каким образом возможно получить уникальную строчку для каждой записи?

При публикации новости, необходима уникальная строчка для url. Главное, чтобы она была как можно короче...

Как я понимаю, пользоваться различными генераторами ключей, на примере

```
    function generateCode($length = 6) {

    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRQSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    $code = "";
 
    $clen = strlen($chars) - 1;  
    while(strlen($code) < $length)
        $code .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$clen)];

    return $code;

}
```

Рано ли поздно, сгенерирует ключ который уже есть в бд. Делать проверку и генерировать каждый раз новый и снова делать проверку о наличии записи в бд. Это слишком накладно.

Какие варианты есть для реализации подобной задачи?

Comment: Да просто пиши время создания публикации да и всё. В формате UnixTime это будет просто строка типа 1672743319.

Comment: Что если в url использовать id записи, может ли в дальнейшем это вызвать трудности?

Comment: Как раз-таки лучше ID записи и использовать